# Recurring task for Microsoft Planner using Power Automate

Tags: microsoft-planner

I'm trying to create an recurring event in Microsoft Planner using Power Automate.

I'm getting the following error message:

InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Create_a_task' inputs at line '1' and column '11262': 'The template function 'uctnow' is not defined or not valid.'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just your utcNow case is wrong, as per your example it should be:

```
addHours(utcNow(), 6)
```